# Translation of “so” (“I think so”, “So, anyway”)

Tags: traduction, anglais, oral

Having just read a [post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19394/is-so-a-pronoun) on StackExchange English about ‘so’, how would you translate it into French, as in ‘I think so’ or ‘So, anyway’. Would you use *‘ça’* ?

Comment: So so, I'm so sorry, but so I will tell you: It is so that this word has so many different meanings in English—so far I can count maybe 7 or so—so that no translation could possibly encompass them all. So, had you been expecting so much, please pardon me, I thought I had to tell you so. (And despite playing with it, I'm not so completely sure my English is correct...)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez it's perfect.

Answer (score 7):

For what my English grammar knowledge is worth¹, that's some kind of reflexive pronoun, about a non-human object. I'd translate that as *“le”*, as in :

> Je le² pense (bien).

You could also translate it with *“ça”*, hence :

> C'est ce que je pense.

---

“So” in “so, anyway”, as far as I know, doesn't have anything to do, and is merely some oral punctuation (is that what you're tagging “oral” for ?). This could translate³ to *“donc”*, or *“alors”*, not bearing much meaning :

> **Bon, alors…** ⁵
>   Donc, euh…

---

¹ Not much.
² Actually, if I were to say that, I'd omit the *le* and say *“Je pense bien”*, but it'd still be implicit.
³ I have a hard time translating it as I use “anyway”⁴ more and more myself (in “french”).
⁴ *En **anglais** dans le texte.*
⁵ Thanks to Evpok.

Comment: "Je le pense" is technicly correct. However, it is very (<=)19th century. I have never heard it except in historical movies.

Comment: @oli: Note 2 is somehow important. I'll have a hard time believing you never heard *"je pense bien"* in France.

Comment: Peut-être est-ce différent au Canada et en France... Je n'ai entendu que des gens dire "Oui, je pense"... Mais ça implique qu'il n'est pas complètement s^ur.. "Effectivement" ou "En effet" sont plus affirmatifs.

Comment: "Je pense bien" est *très* affirmatif (j'ai beau être **à** Montréal, je suis avant tout français européen).

Answer (score 5):

When a *grammar* (and not even a dictionnary) has three pages on the use of a word, you may be sure that it hasn't a simple traduction. To be idiomatic, you'll need to take the context into account.

For the given examples:

> I think so.

*Je le pense (aussi)*, *c'est ce que je pense aussi*, *c'est bien ce que je pense*.

> So, anyway...

*Bon, de toute façon...*

---

Un mot dont l'usage prend trois pages d'explication dans une grammaire, c'est le genre de mot qui n'a pas de traduction hors contexte. Pour les deux exemples donnés :

> I think so.

*Je le pense (aussi)*, *c'est ce que je pense aussi*, *c'est bien ce que je pense*.

> So, anyway...

*Bon, de toute façon...*

Comment: Au départ, je n'aimais pas du tout cette réponse (comment ça, « pas de traduction » ?), mais au vu de toutes les possibilités postées, je commence à y croire. +1 si c'était répondu dans la même langue que la question.

Answer (score 5):

Personnally I link the English 'so' with the French '*ainsi*', meaning 'this way'.
*I think so* is the same as *I think this way*, in French one could say:

- *Je pense ainsi.*
- *C'est ce que je pense.*
- *Je le pense.*

In 'So, anyway' the 'so' has a totally different meaning... it's almost just an interjection... That would be translated to:

- 'Soit'
- 'Enfin bref'
- 'Bon, quoi qu'il en soit'...

**Edit**: Be careful '*quoi qu'il en soit*' only stands for 'anyway', and as @LeVieuxGildas has remarked, the '*soit*' in '*quoi qu'il en soit*' doesn't correspond to 'so', it is really the verb 'être' conjugated in this case.

Comment: *“Soit”*, the verb *“être”* ? That's hardly an interjection… In your translation, “so” is rather translated into *“bon”*, don't you think ? Apart from that, I agree *“ainsi”* is the closest French equivalent to “so”, in terms of meaning (well founded :) ; but it's nowhere near as often used, so the translations sound a little awkward.

Comment: @LeVieuxGildas He said "so" was almost just an interjection, not that *soit* is.

Comment: @Kareen Sure thing, but I tend to more easily translate interjections into interjections ; or to the very least, not into the most meaningful verb of the destination language. I highlight there's a big difference of meaning between both. (And, really, *“quoiqu'il en soit”* translates “anyway”, so…)

Comment: @LeVieuxGildas Mmm... as I am french, and not a french teacher, I just say what's on my mind... on my tongue to be more precise. I personally often use 'Soit' as an empty word/sentence like a synonym of 'Bon, bref'.

Comment: Oh, don't worry, I do the exact same thing ; I just think your second paragraph is not internally coherent ("so" isn't mapped to "soit" in your translation), so I try to help improving it. Sorry if I do a crappy job at that. If you think I'm wrong, just dismiss what I say, no harm done ;) (well, ideally, dismiss *and* leave me a message in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/chez-cosette) or something to help me understand why, but…) Welcome, by the way :·)

Comment: No problem, no crappy job perceived on my side. But I insist: I translate 'So.' by 'Soit." ;-)

Comment: This answer has my preference for the first meaning. About the second, your propositions are rather good, but *enfin bref* sounds *so* accurate... :-)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez I have added your suggestion which does sound *so* accurate ;-)

Answer (score 5):

1) I think that the most common equivalent of "I think so" is:

> Oui, je pense.

Of course there are many other ways to say that, such as:

> En effet. Effectivement. Probablement.

or just: "oui".

2) For the second sentence, which has a very different meaning. People often says stuff like:

> Enfin, bref.

(i.e. okay, I/we have said everything on that topic, let's conclude or change the topic of conversation)

> Voilà.

(i.e. That was what I/we had to say. Let's speak about something else.)

any many others....

Comment: *Enfin bref* est très bien trouvé !